# 'Non exhaustive patterns in function' error when declaring a function within ghci

Tags: haskell

I have a haskell file, sum.hs, that reads:

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' [] = 0
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
```

This works as expected within ghci by loading the module in.

However, if I try to declare the function within ghci I get an error:

```
Prelude> sum' [] = 0
Prelude> sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs
Prelude> sum' [3,4]
*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function sum'
```

Please can someone explain why loading the module in works but declaring the function within ghci results in this error?

Comment: Note that the definition you wrote in the question is incorrect, it should be `xs` rather than `x` in the argument to `sum'`

Comment: whoops! Copy and paste error - thanks for spotting.