# Can't do partial function definitions in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

For some reason partial function definitions in GHCi always lead to some issues so partially defined functions never work for me.

For example, if I do this in the source file:

```
factorial 1 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial(n - 1)
```

all works correctly. If I do the same in GHCi, I get a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77877682/cant-do-partial-function-definitions-in-ghci) exception:

```
ghci> fact 1 = 1
ghci> fact n = n * fact(n - 1)
ghci> fact 5
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Or if I define recursive list length function, all works fine if defined in the source file, but if I do it in GHCI, I get exception about a non-exhaustive pattern:

```
ghci> my_length [] = 0
ghci> my_length (x:xs) = 1 + my_length xs
ghci> my_length [1, 2, 3]
*** Exception: <interactive>:3:1-35: Non-exhaustive patterns in function my_length
```

Is there some trick to partial definitions in GHCi? The [tutorial I'm following](http://users.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Ehal/docs/daume02yaht.pdf) seems to think it should be possible.

Comment: In GHCI you actually redefine the previous definition of function. Try `factorial 1 = 1; factorial n = n * factorial(n - 1)`, that will be a single command.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines

Comment: There are various similar questions over the years, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738392), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374017), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035), but most of them seem to be badly out-of-date, with references to `let` and similar things in either the question or answer that make them not *quite* duplicates (in my opinion). So, although my favorite thing to do is to close a question as a duplicate, I'm not going to in this case -- and am recording my reasoning here for consideration by other folks with a similar impulse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr: *don't* wirte multi-line definitions in GHCi**

When you write this

```
ghci> fact 1 = 1
ghci> fact n = n * fact(n - 1)
ghci> fact 5
```

the interpreter actually sees it as something like

```
ghci> let fact 1 = 1
ghci> let fact' n = n * fact' (n - 1)
ghci> fact' 5
```

(In old versions of GHCi you actually had to write out `let`, which was relaxed at some point - a mistake in my opinion.)

The reason the disambiguation `foo` vs `foo'` is done is **a)** that it allows you to "change definitions" while trying out stuff. Say you previously defined `foo x = x+1`, but further experiments show you actually want `foo x = x+2`. Well, you can just write that and the old definition will get shadowed by it. ...

⎡ Side note: I tend to say this isn't really working great. The problem is that other definitions you've previously made based on the old `foo` will still refer to that old one:

```
ghci> let foo x = x+1
ghci> let bar y = foo y - 1
ghci> bar 19
19
ghci> let foo x = x+2
ghci> bar 19
19
ghci> let bar y = foo y - 1
ghci> bar 19
20
```

⎣

...**b)** that the interpreter doesn't need to re-open definitions that could already have been complete. See, Haskell doesn't require that a definition is actually exhaustive; the line

```
ghci> let fact 1 = 1
```

is in principle a valid definition (albeit useless). It is *good practice* to make all definitions exhaustive and theoretically GHCi could simply wait until it is complete, but it doesn't do that.

What it does offer instead is the multiline mode, enabled thus:

```
ghci> :set +m
ghci> let fact 1 = 1
ghci|     fact n = n * fact (n-1)
ghci| 
ghci> fact 4
24
```

It also has a special `:{` `:}` syntax, but I would advise against using that.

Even multiline mode isn't working *great*, in particular it makes it awkward to go back with up-arrow and change a definition: you'll actually need to go through all the lines and enter them again in the right order.

Upshot: it's best to avoid making any big definitions in GHCi. Much better to put them in a `.hs` source file and load that from GHCi.